# DiscordPy Rewrite ~ Poll with Persentage

Tags: python-3.x, math, discord.py

so, i made a poll command, but i want it to calculate the percentage of the votes, so if 1 Yes, 0 Neutral, 0 No, Yes would be 100%, the code i made right now is

[The code](https://pastebin.com/PWfyJYw3)

The Poll Work but the percentage dosent, i also tried some other calculations but it didnt work. Any help would be appreciated

Method i tried

```py
yes * ((no * 100) + (neutral * 100)) / 100
(yes * 100) + (no * 100) + (neutral * 100) / 100
```

and the result is above 100% and below 0%, so it's 500%, -1260%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your error lies in the math.
percentages are calculated:

`( {votes_for_specific_case} / {sum_of_all_votes_of_all_cases} ) * 100`

also maybe create a template for your status message and use that as they aren't consistent in what you display

Comment: That works, and probably add some description, because at first glance, i don't know what does `votes_for_case` is, and aparently, its the amount of votes, thanks anyways